# How can i assing a different class after a success ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm working in a net core app, i made a HttpPost function to know if an user marked like.
This is the function code:

```
var likesCancion = (from likesCanc in _context.table
                               where likesCanc.SongId == idCancion && likesCanc.UserId == idUser
                               select likesCanc.Likes).FirstOrDefault();

            if (likesCancion == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

I have this:

```
<div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                            <i class="far fa-heart" id="heart"  data-idAudio = @song.Id>
                                <span class="badge"  >@song.Likes</span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
```

This is the `<div>` that I want to change at the start of the page if the user liked it or not.
The **@song.Likes** its data filled from the database.

I made an ajax request inside a for loop and get the respond of my HttpPost function:

```
const iconosCorazon = document.querySelectorAll('#heart');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                        let idUser = $('#inputidUsuario').val();

                            function makeRequest(i) 
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "checkHeart",
                                    data: { idCancion: i, idUser: idUser },
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    success: function (msg) {
                                        console.log(msg);
                                        **if (msg == 1) {
                                            $('.fa-heart').removeClass("far text-dark");
                                            $('.fa-heart').addClass("fa text-danger");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        { 
                                            $('.fa-heart').removeClass("fa text-danger");
                                            $('.fa-heart').addClass("far fa-heart");
                                        }**
                                    },
                                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                                        console.log(msg);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            for (var i=0;i<iconosCorazon.length;i++) {
                                let idCancion = iconosCorazon[i].getAttribute('data-idAudio');
                                makeRequest(idCancion);
                               
                            }
```

I want to assign the css class to the correct element coming from the function result.

The issue here its that ajax execute all the elements at once and change the classes only with the last lopped element. So the question is how can i assign the rigth class to each div element. eg: If result == 1 paint red, if result == 0 paint other color.
Sorry for my bad english

Im trying to make this code works

Comment: Using eq(index) should help you solve the problem. Please try it out and look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(".fa-heart:eq(index)")` to locate the each element with same class name. Sample code below:

```
$(".div_test:eq(0)").css("border","2px solid yellow");
```

**Test Result:**

[image]